# Make header text editable on image button click in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

How to make a header text editable on click of an image button in angular.js? Also how to save the updated value?

```html
<h3 class="m-t-lg m-b-sm inline-block " id="line{{lineId}}">{{headingLineContent}}</h3>
<a href="" class="disabled"><i class="fa fa-pencil pencil m-l-sm"z></i></a>
```

Here id and text are dynamic.

Comment: Please improve your question, what do you mean by label? What have you done so far? Question too vague.

Comment: Welcome to SO.. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking questions.

Comment: Updated my query ..

Comment: Working on something here: http://jsfiddle.net/emporio/h1zsw5nu/1/

Comment: Does not work. Header text and image button are different tags . My condition is on click the image button , header text will be editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you could make use of the x-editable dependency: https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/

Here is an example of how it's done:

```
<h4>Angular-xeditable Text (Bootstrap 3)</h4>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <a href="#" editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</a>
</div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: 'awesome user'
  };
});
```

See the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/emporio/h1zsw5nu/

And here is the solution to your problem specifically: http://jsfiddle.net/emporio/c3kczqpr/